# Printing out mutated vowel with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating the Table headers for my responsive Table in CSS like this:

```
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Abfahrtszeitpunkt"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Startort"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Zielort"; }
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Karte"; }
td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Bewertung"; }
td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Fahrt löschen"; }
```

But when I load this table in my webbrowser the "ö" doesn't get shown in the correct way. The webside only prints out a rhomb with a question mark in it. I already tried fixing it with html and javascript, but it doesnt work. Is there a easy way to fix my problem?

Comment: Unicode encoding issue?

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing this instead of putting your content in the HTML, where it belongs?

Comment: Yes there is. I am trying to make a responsive table, where the information in the table header will (after an min amount of px) function as column for the table and this was the only way how it works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to be specific without more to go on, but somewhere something is being interpreted in one character encoding when in fact it's another. It's useful to make sure your entire stack is using the *same* encoding (UTF-8, for instance). Obligatory link: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

As a *workaround*, you can use `\f6` for `ö` in your CSS (in HTML, you'd use `&ouml;`), but that's a *workaround*, not a solution. The solution is to ensure that your files are encoded consistently, and that your server is serving them with the necessary headers to say what that encoding is. Here's a checklist:

- Choose an encoding. UTF-8 is a hugely popular choice for western texts, well-supported by tools.
- Your editor and other content-generation tools: Make sure they know you want to work in UTF-8, not the default encoding for your operating system (which varies; for a number of modern *nix systems, it's UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1; for Windows, it's ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 [which are *very* similar]).
- Your database: If you have a DB in your stack, you'll want to ensure that the text columns in your tables are using the correct encoding.
- Your web server: Ensure that it's set to deliver files with a correct and complete `Content-Type` header, such as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` (for HTML files)
- I always put the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` meta tag at the top of the `head` of my HTML files. This is mostly so that if I open them directly from the file system in a browser (rather than through a server), the browser knows what encoding I'm using on them. Some HTML editors are smart enough to see it and make sure they work in the named encoding as well.

Comment: Thanks for the long an detailed post i will try to fix it with all this information!